# how to prevent data empty in db when no file upload on editing that file in php

Tags: php, mysql

Let me explain my problem briefly.I have image names in MYSQL database.
I need to change the image name when user uploads a new image using file input field.Otherwise the image name in database remain same.But My problem is when user doesn't upload any images the image name becomes empty in database.

My HTML code for changing a image

```
      <form method="post" action="edit_store_img.php?id=<?php echo (int)$store['id'] ?>" class="clearfix"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i>
              </span>
              <label for="file">Upload a store image</label>
              <input type="file" name="storepic" value="<?php echo $store['pic']; ?>"/>
           </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <br>

          <h3>Change Map Image For Store <?php echo remove_junk($store['name']);?></h3>
          <hr>

           <!-- below code is for map image -->
          <?php if($store['pic'] === '0'): ?>
                          <img class="img-avatar img-circle" src="uploads/mapimg/no_image.jpg" alt="Store_map_picture" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;">  
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <img class="img-avatar img-circle" src="uploads/mapimg/<?php echo $store['map']; ?>" alt="Store_map_picture" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;">  
                      <?php endif; 
          ?>
     </div>      

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></i>
              </span>
               <label for="file">Upload a Store map location image</label>
              <input type="file" name="mappic" value="<?php echo $store['map']; ?>"/>
           </div>
          </div>

        <div class="col-md-12"> 
          <button type="submit" name="edit_store_img" class="add-btn">Update Store image</button>
        </div> 
  </form>
```

This is my PHP file for getting ID for that particular image

```
<?php
  $store = find_by_id('store',(int)$_GET['id']);
  if(!$store)
  {
    $session->msg("d","Missing store id.");
    redirect('store.php');
  }
?>
```

This is my PHP code for Storing image name in database

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['edit_store_img']))
        {
         if(empty($errors))
         {
                 /*below queries is for image upload */
                $msg = "";
                $map = $_FILES["mappic"]["name"];
                $tempname = $_FILES["mappic"]["tmp_name"];    
                $mapfolder = "uploads/mapimg/".$map;    
                 // Now let's move the uploaded image into the mapfolder: image
                    if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $mapfolder))  {
                        $msg = "map Image uploaded successfully"; 
                    }else{
                        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
                  }
                  $message = "";
                $pic = $_FILES["storepic"]["name"];
                $tempname = $_FILES["storepic"]["tmp_name"];    
                $picfolder = "uploads/storeimg/".$pic;

                 // Now let's move the uploaded image into the folder image
                    if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $picfolder))  {
                        $message = "Image uploaded successfully"; 
                    }else{
                        $message = "Failed to upload image";
                  }
                   $query   = "UPDATE store SET";
                   $query  .=" map ='{$map}', pic ='{$pic}'";  
                   $query  .=" WHERE id ='{$store['id']}'";
                   $result = $db->query($query);
                           if($result && $db->affected_rows() === 1){
                             $session->msg('s',"store updated ");
                             redirect('store.php', false);
                           } else {
                             $session->msg('d',' Sorry failed to updated!');
                             redirect('edit_store_img.php?id='.$store['id'], false);
                           }
           } 
           else
           {
               $session->msg("d", $errors);
               redirect('edit_store_img.php?id='.$store['id'], false);
           }
        }
      ?>
```

I Need to store image name when user doesn't upload image.I need to avoid the image name db field becomes empty.

Comment: if you changed `if(empty($errors))` to `if(empty($errors) && !empty( $_FILES["storepic"] ) )` it would prevent the code from performing the `update` statement if no image is uploaded

Comment: it's preventing to image name in db field became empty.but when I uploads a new image name it doesn't change my db field. please look at my whole code if you have time [link](https://textuploader.com/tspb5)

Comment: The [code you posted](https://textuploader.com/tspb5) has an unbalanced number of opening/closing `div` tags. Also - you changed the line as mentioned above ( or nearly ) but made the condition look at two file inputs which was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Sorry for that. I just updated my whole neat code.

Comment: Why do you use `if($store['pic'] === '0'` as a test for both the `storeimg` and the `mapimg` blocks of code? And why would there be a value of zero at any point for an image?

Comment: `if(empty($errors) && ($store['pic'] === '0') && ($store['map'] === '0'))` and   `if(empty($errors) && !empty( $_FILES["storepic"]["name"]) && !empty($_FILES["mappic"]["name"]))` both are preventing db to not be empty but it doesn't allow to upload new images i don't know why but hopefully   `$query  .=" map = IF('{$map}' != '', '{$map}', map), pic = IF('{$pic}' != '', '{$pic}', pic)";`  fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below quirky will somehow fix  your problem; however, this is not the correct way I think;

```
$query  .=" map = IF('{$map}' != '', '{$map}', map), pic = IF('{$pic}' != '', '{$pic}', pic)";
```

We are just asking the database to update with the exiting column value if the passed value is empty.

The correct way should be not to take it for granted that the user have uploaded a file; as you are doing with these below lines in your code;

```
$map = $_FILES["mappic"]["name"];
...
$pic = $_FILES["storepic"]["name"];
```

You should be actually using IF conditions to check if some viable value has been set for those _FILES variables so you know what to process for and what not, and prepare your SQL UPDATE statement accordingly.